# How can I restore missing "generate sample content" functionality for new Flutter projects in IntelliJ IDEA CE?

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

The ability of the "generate sample content" popup menu for a new Flutter project in IntelliJ IDEA seems to have disappeared on my installation. (It used to work until recently)  (IntelliJ IDEA CE 2019.1.1 Build #IC-191.6707.61, Apr 16, 2019, on macOS 10.14.4)

When I click the checkbox to enable the popup menu, the menu is not populated - its just blank.  I've re-installed IntelliJ IDEA, as well as run *flutter doctor* in the terminal (no errors from *flutter doctor*), but the popup menu remains empty.

Does anybody know how to get this menu to be re-populated?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and I noticed that my Android SDK was not configured correctly in IntelliJ. After specifying the path to my SDK in IntelliJ's settings I can now use the "generate sample content" functionality.

Go to `IntelliJ > Preferences > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK` and specify the Android SDK location. Presumed you've installed the Android SDK already, you'll find it on Mac OS by default at `/Users/<user-name>/Library/Android/sdk` and on Windows at `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`.

Make sure to update your IntelliJ version, Dart & Flutter plugin, Android SDK and run `flutter doctor` to check if everything is set up correctly.

Also checkout this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31916), which describes the same problem.